# how to use android support library

Tags: android, tags

In the 13th revision of the v4 support library, google introduced the SlidingPaneLayout. I don't know how should I start implementing it, and the documentation doesn't really seem to help. Could someone please clarify this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlidingPanelLayout is a layout which provides sliding facility with two different views.

- left side: The master part. It usually contains a list of values (i.e. Contacts and so on)
- right side: The detail part. It contains the details of the values in the left side

This component helps us to divide the available screen space in two different sides that doesn’t overlap and can be  sledded horizontally.

Visit this **[Tutorial Link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html)** to understand step by step implementation of it.

[image: SlidingPanelLayout]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange requirement. Are you sure you've understood it correctly?

if all the three client sends their request at exactly the same time

There's no such thing as 'exactly the same time' in a network. (A) It is undiscoverable, and (b) the network is a sequential mediuem. So the connect requests will arrive in a sequence, not simultaneously. To be specific, accept() will return one Socket at a time, in whatever order your local TCP stack decides is appropriate.

Do I need to create an array of socket to handle these three request independently

I don't see why. You just need to create Socket variables to store the result of each accept(), and handle each Socket in a separate thread.

If I use a single incomingLink socket

You can't. The suggestion doesn't make sense. Each accepted Socket is a separate object.

Will the underlying transport protocol(TCP/UDP) do the work for me to handle these simultaneous requests by buffering them to buffer, and maintaining a proper order and then supply them one after another to my ServerSocket

Yes, see above.

so that my single incomingLink Socket will handle them properly?

I don't know what this means.